# Two simultaneous api calls, redux state properties becomes empty

Tags: reactjs, redux

I call two action creators from a view component, which triggers two api calls from redux-sagas.

Both reducers have the same Action type - I don't know if that's good or bad, but it means that both reducers are triggered even if the data is handled by the other reducer.

Here is the first reducer:

```
case ADD_THINGS:
  return {
    ...state,
    termNodes: {
      ...action.payload.termNodes,
    },
    terms: {
      ...action.payload.terms,
    },
};
```

And the next one:

```
case ADD_THINGS: 
  return {
    ...state,
    ...action.payload.shippingProfiles,
  };
default:
  return state;
```

The result is that on the first ADD_THINGS, both terms and shippingProfiles data gets put into state correctly, but on the second ADD_THINGS, both shippingProfiles and term data becomes empty.

In redux devtools I see:

```
ADD_THINGS <--- data is available on both shippingProfiles and terms
ADD_THINGS <--- shippingProfiles and terms data is gone
```

I don't understand how on the first ADD_THINGS both data gets synced and put into state correclty  , and I also don't understand how both data gets erased? Any ideas?

Comment: Please edit your question to include examples of what `state` is before and after your reducers run, and the value of `action.payload`.

Comment: It's bad, the action types should be unique. Namespace them into objects for example, so that you can do `A.ADD_THINGS` and `B.ADD_THINGS`.

Comment: You should add a `break` between each case.